# Error: The Cordova command-line interface is not installed on your system path

Tags: cordova-plugins

I am getting above error when running my app using mfpdev app preview command. I have tried its online solution but not succeed. So anybody know this problem and its possible solution.

Comment: Is it Windows? Add the appropriate tag. Also the language tag. And have you checked whether the Cordova CLI is installed or not?

Comment: yes i have checked that cordova is installed in my Ubantu machine which have latest version. For developing app i had used angular js with cordova. when i run app in ubantu terminal above error appeared. I have also checked in console but no error. I am not able to view and run my android app in android simulator bcoz of above error.

Answer (score 0):

**Cause:**

After verifying from mfpdev's source code, this error message is thrown when,

1. Cordova faced some file access permission issue while coping files.
2. Some error is throwing in  Cordova Prepare process.

**Solution**

First try with

```
cordova prepare
```

and

```
cordova build
```

Then resolve all problems  they are throwing.

Then try again with `mfpdev app preview` .